# Getting the value of Foreign key values in Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I just want to get the clientType.name through an `ID` of foreign key from `Clients table` and pass it to jsonResponse , I have tried but it doesn't work below

I tried **select_related** but it doesn't work
it says `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`

```
def patientdetails(request):

    patient_id = request.POST.get('patient')
    context = {
       'company' : Clients.objects.filter(id=patient_id).select_related()

    }
    qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', context)
    return JsonResponse({'data': qs_json})
```

**models.py**

```
class ClientType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'client_type'


class Clients(models.Model):
     client_type = models.ForeignKey(ClientType, models.DO_NOTHING)
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
     middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
     birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
     sex = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
     occupation = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

     class Meta:
         managed = True
         db_table = 'clients'
```

**Result data in javascript**

```
}).done(function(data){
      var resultdata = JSON.parse(data.data);

});
```

Comment: I ran the script on my side and it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @themorgan
 thanks for the response but I think the problem is the way how I assign my data into `JsonResponse` did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related): you need to pass a str.

```
Clients.objects.filter(id=patient_id).select_related("clientType__name")
```

Comment: but I will pass it through `JsonResponse`  did I miss something in my format?

Comment: @McLarvel you should post the complete stack trace log, I think it's the error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `from django.core import serializers`

You can try to add nested fields you need in [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields) parameter

```
def patientdetails(request):
    patient_id = request.POST.get('patient')
    clients = Clients.objects.filter(id=patient_id)
    qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', clients, fields=['your_fields'..., 'client_type__name'])
    return JsonResponse({'data': qs_json})
```

Comment: I tried this but it the data from table client_type.name didn't reflect when I print it.

Comment: I gues you can get it by `client_type__name` key. Just look whole object in you console in browser, `client_type__name` should be there. `console.log(resultdata)` in js

Comment: yes, it returns an object and it has a value but the foreign key value in my client_type.name didn't reflect at all in the object.  this is my console  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB8ux.png)  should I put select_related?

Comment: If you add `client_type__name` to fields, it strange that you didn't see it in console. May be `name` of this ClientType in this Client is null?

Comment: There is data but it didn't reflect in console at all :( please see this images  , [client table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81FAb.png) [client type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zG2B.png)

Comment: is there another way just to get the foreign key data? and pass it to jsonresponse?